# Using NSPredicate to find elements in an NSArray similar to SQL WHERE IN clause

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nspredicate

I have an NSArray of, say Article objects. Article object contains another NSArray of tags to the article. 
So I want to find articles that contain a set of tags like [iphone, apple, music].
In SQL it would be like: `WHERE tags IN ('iphone', 'apple', 'music')`. 
So far I have only found how to use NSPredicate to finds elements by single value:

```
NSArray *filteredItems = [article filteredArrayUsingPredicate:
                                       [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"tag == %@", @"iphone"]];
```

Is there a way to do what I need to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`NSCompoundPredicate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCompoundPredicate_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to merge together various `NSPredicate` objects like this:

```
NSMutableArray *predicates = [NSMutableArray array];

[predicates addObject:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"tag == %@", @"iphone"]]];
[predicates addObject:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"tag == %@", @"apple"]]];
[predicates addObject:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"tag == %@", @"music"]]];

//Create a predicate using AND
NSPredicate *compoundANDpred = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:predicates];

//Create a predicate using OR
NSPredicate *compoundORpred = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:predicates];
```

or you could use a predicate with ANY and IN, as outlined in some of the other answers.

Comment: I set this answer as accepted because this covers the topic much wider. This is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 2):

You can use ANY and IN clause

`NSArray *tags = ...;
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY tags.name IN %@",tags]`

Comment: This worked, but I had to convert NSArray *tags ... into NSString in order it to work! Thank you.

Comment: @user3697016 If you have an array of NSManagedObject's - @"ANY tags IN %@",tags

Answer (score 0):

You wan use the predicate like below

```
NSPredicate *template = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"tag == %@ OR tag == %@ OR tag == %@",@"iphone",@"apple",@"music"];
```

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done like this

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"tag == %@", @[@"iphone", @"apple", @"music"]];
NSArray *result = [dataArray filterUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Comment: Your function returns void, as you perform the filtering on the dataArray itself. Use instead - (NSArray<ObjectType> *)filteredArrayUsingPredicate:(NSPredicate *)predicate;